# In symfony form how can I validate a parmeter is an integer, and generate an error if it is a float?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, integer

Symfony form allows floats though without error and is silently rounding. How can I raise an error if the input value is a float?

My entity look like this;

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Charge
{

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Amount is required.")
     * @Assert\Type(type="int", message="Amount must be an integer.")
     */
    protected $amount;
}
```

My form looks like this;

```
class NewChargeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('amount', Type\IntegerType::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to add `Regex` validation to require integers only

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Charge
{

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Amount is required.")
     * @Assert\Type(type="int", message="Amount must be an integer.")
     * @Assert\Regex("/^-?[0-9]\d*$/", message="Amount must be an integer.")
     */
    protected $amount;
}
```